# How can I remove sprites when they are outside viewport, but then add them again if I return to their location to save memory

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, sprite-kit

I'm creating an open-world RPG like Neverwinter nights. But I'm worried about memory and am afraid if I just populate a huge world with physics-based sprite nodes, I won't have any memory for anything else.

To combat this, I want to remove the sprites when they go far outside of the viewport and then re-add those sprites when I get close to their location.

How could I accomplish this?

To any and all who take time to help me with this, thank you!

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should probably try asking in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @sangony sorry but how is asking how to add and remove sprites based on player location too broad. Is it because I mentioned the reason I want to do so being to save memory? (Prompting people to address that leading to more of a discussion post) if so I’ll just delete the to save memory part. Although I want memory to be kept in mind and not just a random .remove this / . Add in an if update function

Comment: @sangony and thank you for the link. I had no idea their was a game dev stack exchange

Comment: Asking a question on SO can be really frustrating. I've been there myself. Your question broad because it is partially opinion based due to the fact that it has many possible solutions. An answer would also have to take into account everything else going on in your code which is.... you guessed it.... very broad.  This explains it in much more detail https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking . As for the other site, there are MANY Stack Exchanges. A link is here https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: @sagony oh okay, that makes sense :(. Thanks for the great reply! Unfortunately game dev seems pretty dead. So I’ll come back when I’ve tried myself and run into a more specific problem on why what I’m trying isn’t working the way I want it to. Going to do my menu first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all data on a database like CoreData with exact parameters you need like states and positions whatever do you need.

Then you can create a method to get all objects on a specific position with radius and use this method when the player moves or when you need to check things like a quest on another site, take those objects and compare with current objects, place again on the correct site the new ones and remove the old ones (they are not on radius probably or disappears for another reason)

This is a complex approach but it could work.